# how to insert data through VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, syntax-error

I am trying to pass my query string into database using VB.NET, but I am seeing a syntax error. I don't know where it is, please help me!

```
Me.str = String.Concat(New String() 
    {"Insert into Sales values('", 
        Me.txtVoucherNo.Text, "','", dtpDate.Value, "','", 
        dtpMonth.Value, "','", POSPage.txtPatientNo.Text, "','", 
        POSPage.txtPatientName.Text, "','", 
        POSPage.txtAddress.Text, ",'--',", POSPage.txtsubtotal.Text, "','", 
        POSPage.txtTax.Text, ",'--',", POSPage.txtdiscount.Text, "','", 
        POSPage.txtGrandTotal.Text, "')"})
```

Comment: 1) You should never concatenate strings to make a SQL statement. Please read up on SQL Injection.......... 2) You don't say what the error is; please provide the error message.

Comment: You should be using parametized queries, instead of string concatenation.  Besides being insecure, as @SpectralGhost points out, its likely also the cause of your syntax error.  Print out `Me.str` and show us what's in it so we can tell for sure.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I don't know if he's having SQL syntax issues or issues on the line of code he posted.... It could be the SQL string is malformed(especially with the -- and a string concatenated in front of it.

Comment: the error is "syntax error near ','."

Comment: @SpectralGhost  Actually, I was assuming that the SQL string *was* malformed by poor escaping of the injected text and that that was what's causing his syntax error in SQL.  Of course it could be malformed even if the injections are properly escaped, that's why we need the actual string text.

Answer (score 0):

### Nooooooooooooo!

String edits like that leave you vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked.

You want something more like this:

```vb
Using cn As New SqlConnection(" connection string here "), _
      cmd As New SqlCommand( 
                 "Insert into Sales VALUES ( @VoucherNo, @Date, @Month, @PatientNo, @PatientName, @Address, '--', @SubTotal, @Tax, '--', @Discount, @GrandTotal )"
                 , cn )

    'change this to use the actual column types and lengths in your database
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@VoucherNo", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10).Value = Me.txtVoucherNo.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dtpDate.Value
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Month", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dtpMonth.Value
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PatientNo", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10).Value = POSPage.txtPatientNo.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PatientName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = POSPage.txtPatientName.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250).Value = POSPage.txtAddress.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SubTotal", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(POSPage.txtsubtotal.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Tax", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(POSPage.txtTax.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Discount", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(POSPage.txtdiscount.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@GrandTotal", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(POSPage.txtGrandTotal.Text)

    cn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

End Using
```

Note that, with this code, the SQL string itself is **constant**. Instead of a string field in your class (`Me.Str`), you need the full SqlCommand object, so that you can hold both the sql statement and the parameter data.

If you still have trouble with this, try including the names of the columns before the `VALUES()` clause.

That out of the way, original syntax error was because of this sequence in your string array:

```
 "','", POSPage.txtAddress.Text, ",'--',"
```

Note that this would open a quoted field in your query, but not close it until after the comma. What comes next is a comment marker in Sql Server. In short, if you actually enter the name of the field as the address, you'd get this:

```
'POSPage.txtAddress.Text,'--
```

Everything after the two hyphens would be commented out, including the closing parentheses for your VALUES clause, meaning the query is not valid SQL syntax... assuming someone hasn't already used sql injection on another field to include put whatever sql statement they want as part of the query.

I won't tell you how to just fix that error, because it should be obvious now, and well... there's that pesky injection problem again. I will say that you made the same mistake with the other `",'--',"` string later in the query.